# How to get ID of this page

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have the following link of a page. How can I get ID of my page.

This the example page `localhost/xxxx/xxxx/admin.php?page=user-edit&id=2`

I used

```
 $id = isset($_GET['id']);
```

but code still isn't working and this the whole code look like

```
function getid()
{
$id = isset($_GET['id']);

$options = array(
    'upload_dir' => app('path.base') . '/uploads/',
    'upload_url' => App::url('uploads/'),
    'max_file_size' => 5000000, // 5 mb
    'max_width'  => 2000,
    'max_height' => 2000,
    'versions' => array(
        '' => array(
            'crop' => true,
            'max_width'  => 300,
            'max_height' => 300
        ),
    ),
    'upload_start' => function($image, $instance) use ($id) {
        $image->name = "~{$id}.{$image->type}";
    },
    'crop_start' => function($image, $instance) use ($id) {
        $image->name = "{$id}.{$image->type}";
    },
    'crop_complete' => function($image, $instance) use ($id) {
        Usermeta::update($id, 'avatar_image', $image->name);
    }
);

}
```

Comment: Maybe because you assign the return value of `isset()` and NOT the value!

Comment: ` $id = $_GET['id'];` I think this is how you do it.

Comment: do `if(isset()){ //put your $id here}`

Comment: The [`isset()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) returns _`TRUE`_ if the variable is set (exists and has avalue) or _`FALSE`_ if not.

Answer (score 3):

`isset` returns true or false, so you can use short condition with a ternary operator, like this:

```
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : null;
```

Comment: Hi thanks I use this code but the $id only get the null value

Comment: works for sure if You have id passed in Your url in example 'index.php?id=something

Comment: Look on my code and use it, in Your code (if You updated code) there is still $id = isset($_GET['id']);

Comment: Yes sir of course I already use your code and I'm also using it on other function and  working but I don't know only on this function not working

Comment: First sir i have this page with the list of all users

and the URL is http://localhost/user/admin.php?page=users

then when i select user to edit

my url change into this

http://localhost/user/admin.php?page=user-edit&id=2

do i need to get my  page ID? before to get ID of the user?

I try $id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : null; to my other functions and 100% working only on this Url not working

Comment: maybe page=user-edit include other files? There should be no problems with get id, try to get in on the top of admin.php and break the script (die());

Comment: Hi sir this is my current code http://nexusgames.comyr.com/test
and when i use this code $_GET['id'] it always say undefined index

Comment: Its full code? Maybe you include other files and use $_GET there, because this code do not generate undefined index notice for sure.

Comment: ok thanks sir i will upload the whole code later and try your suggestion thankyou

Answer (score 3):

**Try This Code You'll get the answer;**

```
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
     $id = $_GET['id'];
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: Thankyou sir i try this code its working but instead of getting value of the id it will get '0' value or null .

Answer (score 2):

use isset like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])) $id = $_GET['id'];
```

Comment: Thankyou sir i try this code its working but instead of getting value of the id it will get '0' value or null

Answer (score 1):

This is the way to get id from URL.

```
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
   $id = $_GET['id'];
}
else
{
   $id = "";
}
```

Other way to get Query String Value is

The following code will return a JavaScript Object containing the URL parameters:

```
// Read a page's GET URL variables and return them as an associative array.
function getUrlVars()
{
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}
```

For example, if you have the URL:

```
http://www.example.com/?me=myValue&name2=SomeOtherValue
```

This code will return:

```
{
    "me"    : "myValue",
    "name2" : "SomeOtherValue"
}
```

and you can do:

```
var me = getUrlVars()["me"];
var name2 = getUrlVars()["name2"];
```

Comment: Thankyou sir i try this code its working but instead of getting value of the id it will get '0' value or null

Comment: Can you please check all request using `print_r($_REQUEST);`